# Use external panel from dynamically injected page

Tags: jquery-mobile

A new thing in [version 1.4.0 alpha 2 of jQuery-Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/08/15/jquery-mobile-1-4-0-alpha-2-released/) is that [panels](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-alpha.2/demos/widgets/panels/) no longer have to be inside the page that uses them. Instead, external panels can be siblings to the pages.

This works fine with static pages:

```
<div id="panel" data-role="panel" data-theme="b" data-position="left" 
     data-display="push">
  <h3>This is a panel</h3>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="staticPage">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#panel">Panel</a>
    <h1>Static page</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content"> 
    <div class="content-primary">
      <a href="#dynamicPage" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Go to dynamic page</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#panel').panel();
  });
</script>
```

However, when I generate and inject a page dynamically, the link to the panel no longer works as it is supposed to:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="dynamicPageTemplate">
  <div data-role="page" id="staticPage">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <a href="#panel">Panel</a>
      <h1>Dynamic page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
      <div class="content-primary">
        <a href="#staticPage" data-role="button" data-inline="true">
          Go to static page
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
      if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {
          var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
          if (url.hash.search(/^#dynamicPage$/) !== -1) {
              $('#dynamicPage').remove();
              var template = $("#dynamicPageTemplate").html();
              var $page = $(template);
              $page.attr('id', 'dynamicPage');
              $('body').append($page);
              $page.page();
              $.mobile.changePage($page, {changeHash: false});
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      }
  });
</script>
```

When I click the "Panel" button in header of the dynamic page, the URL changes to `…#panel` and nothing is shown. I suspect that jQuery-Mobile tries to show the panel as a page rather than a panel. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

[Fiddle with complete example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Fq7n/1/)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile 1.4 panel (and a lot of other widgets) implementation still don't work correctly. Several new components are not even implemented yet. Not to mention, demo site was not updated since they announced alpha version 1.

Let me get back to pane implementation. It is still under heavy development. Any panel inner content (except buttons) is not properly styled. Just add a listview and see a final result.

Only thing you can do is wait for RC1 versions, or maybe just maybe first beta version (but I wouldn't hold my breath for the beta release).